# Neo4j nodes: showing a-c relations

Tags: neo4j, cypher, nodes, relationship

I've the following relations: `a-b-c`:

```
MATCH (a)-[:relation_x]->(b)-[:relation_y]->(c)
RETURN a,c
```

Now `a` and `c` are not connected. Is there a way to show this relation, without showing b?

Same result with:

```
MATCH (a)-[*2]->(c)
RETURN a, c
```

Comment: what do you mean by show ? neo4j browser visualizations ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install [APOC Procedures](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/) and do it using  `apoc.create.vRelationship`. With tris procedure you can create a virtual relation between two nodes at query time. Try it:

```
MATCH (a)-[:relation_x]->()-[:relation_y]->(c)
CALL apoc.create.vRelationship(a,'relation_type',{},c) yield rel
RETURN *
```

The output will be:

[image: Output]

*Note: Remember to install APOC procedures according the version of Neo4j you are using. Take a look in the [Version Compatibility Matrix](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_version_compatibility_matrix).*

Comment: Thanks! Works great

Comment: Hi @MDub if this answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: Thanks, I am a newbee here ;)

Comment: @MDub haha no problems! I suggest you [take a tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know better the site and learn how things works here. Thanks! :D